# viewDidLayoutSubviews for Custom UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, animation, uikit, tableview

I want to animate a subview of a custom TableViewCell. To perform this animation, the cell needs the width of this subview, which is laid out by an auto-layout-constraint.

However, when I use the animation-function in the cellForRowAtIndex function (`mycell.animate()`), the width is `0`, because the subviews are not laid out yet and the animation will not work.

In a regular view, I would use `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`, because then the view is laid out, I can get the width and perform the animation. However, what's the equivalent function for a custom UITableViewCell?

I tried the `willDisplay` delegate function of the TableView, but when I print out the width of the cells subview, it still says `0`...

Comment: You probably have to create a subclass of UITableViewCell and then go from there.

Comment: hmm I actually have, sorry if that's been unclear

Comment: I know this is probably deeper than that but, have you tried assigning the width to the table cell in `cellForRow:at:`? `cell.frame.size.width = tableView.frame.size.width`

Comment: `layoutSubviews` inside the cell subclass might do the trick.

Comment: lol thanks @lu2302, it really works! Didn't think it can be that easy :)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The correct place is inside [`layoutSubviews`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622482-layoutsubviews):

```
class MyCell : UITableViewCell {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        // do your thing
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to use this approach while adding a gradient to a custom UITableViewCell. I call my `applyGradient()` function inside of `layoutSubviews()` My problem is that when the table loads, I see no gradient, but after I click the cell, the gradient will show. Any idea of why the gradient won't show before clicking? I've tried calling `layoutSubviews()` from different places in my code with no luck. @luk2302

Comment: @Chamanhm i've had your issue and the code above did it without the need to call the function, just put the gradient code within the function above in tableViewCell class :)

Comment: I've had a similar problem while setting shadow for a subview. Apparently, the `layoutSubviews` method doesn't get called after the view has been laid out by autolayout. (or it is returning 0 for some reason)

Comment: layoutSubviews() did not work in my case. After reuse of the cell, gradient frame was wrong, even though i removed gradient and apply it again in reuse.
Updating frame inside `draw(_ rect: CGRect)` solved my problem

Comment: dropping shadow also worked only from `draw(_ rect: CGRect)`

Answer (score 14):

It will work if you animate your view inside draw function in tableViewCell

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    super.draw(rect)

    //Your code here
}
```